# Cannot console log the properties of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm tring to console log the propreties of an object in typescript but it's not working.

```
  setTitleAndBody(result: { title: String; body: String; }) {
    console.log(result)
    console.log(result.title)
  }
```

The most curious in this is that if I do it only for result, I can open the object in my app console and see the informations that are in title and body. But when I wanna console log directly result.title, it's not working. Any idea why this happens? I already tried other ways to access them like `result["title"]`, still not working.

[image]

Comment: If you look closely `title` is empty string at first. I guess you're fetching data and then assigning it to result variable. So by the time you get the response, your `console.log` function has been executed and that's why it is showing empty.

Comment: Have you tried setting the parameter values to a new variable and then logging?  In your log the properties technically show with no value in the preview and then with values in the expanded object.

Comment: @AustinBorn Getting closer I now see [object Object] where I wanna display my result, it was empty before!

Comment: This edit doesn't make a lot of sense: the original code doesn't use setState, so it's completely different from you edit. Also, setState takes objects: put both values in the same object so you're only calling a single setState?

Comment: Thanks for the idea for the setState! And yeah it doesn’t make sense because I didn’t put all the code but it’s all good now it does what I need it to do. I didn’t put it in the first code because the setState wasn’t working so I tried to just console log instead to be able to see the data quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a setTimeout just like that:

```
  setTitleAndBody(result) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({noteTitre: result.title})
      this.setState({noteCorps: result.body})
    }, 100)
  }
```

Comment: Why did creating a timeout resolve the issue?  In what context was the method being used?